# Exclude HTTP authentication from specific Controller

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, .htpasswd

I have an application made in **CakePHP 2** that has a HTTP protection through **.htaccess** file. Already have an exception in a certain directory in `webroot` and works well.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Application"
AuthUserFile /my/application/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

SetEnvIf Request_URI "files/photos/" allow

Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

But now also need an exception for a specific **URL**, which is a *View* of a certain *Controller*. I tried to simply add this line but it did not work, still requesting username and password.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "users/confirmation/" allow
```

I have `UsersController` and `confirmation()` method. The point is that one is a physical path and the other is "virtual".

Any idea for resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the lines containing the paths to be ignored by authentication:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "files/photos/" noauth=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "users/confirmation/*" noauth=1
```

And then, adding the exception with the `REDIRECT_` prefix:

```
Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cakephp Auth then you can exclude some actions of controller from authentication. So write the line below in particular controller e.g. UsersController.

```html
public function beforeFilter()
 {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow('register','forgot_password','reset_password','password','login','logout');
 }
```

Actions written in allow() can be accessed even after there is no authentication. Pass nothing if want to allow whole controller. e.g. $this->Auth->allow();

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question, because I'm using HTTP authentication through `.htaccess` file and not directly on the Auth library. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok. I understood. I'll try for solution. Thank you.